# How is data transferred over RAID Controller?

Tags: raid, controller

in my server I have PCI RAID Controller PERC 6i,
it has two cables connected to SAS Backplane.
one is mentioned with CTRL 1 (connected to J_SAS_A), and the other CTRL 0 (connected to J_SAS_B).

The disks are connected to SAS Backplane.
The SAS Backplane get its power from Power Supply.
SAS Backplane has J_PLANAR_BMC cable connected to the Motherboard.

My question is, does the data on the disks transfer to the motherboard through RAID Controller PCI, or through J_PLANAR_BMC connector?

Comment: What kind of server is this? PowerEdge T 410?

Comment: Yes it is PowerEdge T410

Answer (score 0):

Through the RAID controller. The BMC is just a management interface.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
So does this mean if I plug 6x HDDs 6Gb/s to the backplane, the total throughput will be only 6Gb/s as this is the speed of the controller ?